# NumPy: Assigning to Matrix using Slice Indices vs Lists

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, slice

Given the following code, I expect the last two lines to behave the same, however the don't.

```
import numpy as np

C = np.matrix(np.zeros((4,4)))
C[0, 0:2] = np.matrix([[1, 2]]) # Works as expected.
C[0, [0,1]] = np.matrix([[1, 2]]) # Throws an "array is not broadcastable to correct shape" error.
```

When using an `ndarray` instead, things work as expected (adjusting the right-hand-side of the assignment to a one-dimensional `ndarray`):

```
D = np.zeros((4,4))
D[0, 0:2] = np.array([1, 2]) # Works as expected.
D[0, [0,1]] = np.array([1, 2]) # Works too.
```

And to make things even weirder, if one is only indexing the matrix `C` (as opposed to assigning to it), it seems using slice indices or a list just return the same:

```
C[0, 0:2] # => matrix([[ 1.,  2.]])
C[0, [0, 1]] # => matrix([[ 1.,  2.]])
```

The question is, why is the behavior of the two approaches in assignment different? What am I missing?

(Edit: typo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be a bug in numpy: http://projects.scipy.org/numpy/ticket/803 .  The solution is to assign an ordinary list or numpy array instead of assigning a matrix to the selected elements.

Answer (score -1):

*Edit:* Had to realize that while what I write is true, the fact that `D[0,0:2] = ...` is different from `D[0,[0,1]] = ...` (so for arrays) is maybe a real inconsistency (and related).

Maybe an explenation why this happens as far as I see. Check this:

```
D[0,[0,1]] = np.array([[1,2]])
```

Gives the same error. The thing is that internally the slicing operation takes place before the matrix shape is "fixed" to 2D again, which, since `matrix` is a subclass occurs whenver a new view is created, but here *no* view is created as its unnecessary normally!

This means that when you are setting elements like this, it always behaves like:

```
C.A[0,[0,1]] = matrix([[1,2]])  # Note the C.A giving normal array view of C.
```

Which fails, because the matrix is 2D, but `C.A[0,[0,1]]` is 1D (since it is not "fixed" to be at least 2D by the matrix object), in this case one could say that since its just removing a 1 dimension axis from the right hand side numpy could maybe tolerate it, but as long as it doesn't it would require the matrix object to make a full custom sets of in place/assignment operators which would not be very elegent as well probably.

But maybe the use of `C.A`, etc. can help getting around this inconvenience. On a general note however, in numpy it is better to always use base class arrays unless you are doing a lot of matrix multiplications, etc. (in which case if it is limited to one part of the program, its likely better to just view your arrays as matrixes before it but work with arrays in the rest)

Comment: `D[0,[0,1]] = np.array([[1,2]])` fails because slicing the 2-D `ndarray` gives a 1-D `ndarray` (in this case), and the right hand side is 2-D.

Comment: Sure, but actually 1. `D[0,0:1] = np.array([[1,2]])` works so slicing allows more then fancy indexing. The thing is, its the same for the matrix. For this assignment itself it is does not behave as 2-D. Note that `C[0,[0,1]][...] = np.array([[1,2]])` works because then the matrix is fixed to 2-D before the assignment (I know its not in-place anymore, so nonsense but it proofs the point).

Comment: `matrix` has a custom `__getitem__` to handle (most) of this. But this is `__setitem__` and it behaves exactly the same as an array.